# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Acer Cloudbook 11

Tags: boot, 16.04, live-usb, acer, bios

I want to get Ubuntu on my AO1-131-C58K.

I needed several trys to get no **Blackscreen** after I clicked on "Starting Ubuntu in Live Mode" and then I Installed it and deleted Windows 10 which was on it before. Now I always have:**no bootable device**

I nearly tried everything and I even can't get to the Live Mode anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know cloud books, but booting into a CD should be a BIOS feature. If the device does not have a CD, you should be able to change boot order to first boot from an USB CD drive. That should boot up an Ubuntu live CD. If the CD does not boot, its surely not a Linux issue.

If you get the live CD started, you could open "gparted" and check if your boot partition has the Flag "boot". If not this could be the problem. Then select the disk, right click and select "Manage Flags". Select boot and exit.

Another way is to just update and reinstall grub. Thats quick and easy and very often fixes things. Just open a terminal in your live system and enter

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

This is when you have one hard drive installed (in Linux drive numbering scheme is "sda" the first SATA HDD). That should give you back your start menu and the old Ubuntu installation. Once booted, do run the two commands again from your installation to get rid of a possible boot entries of the live CD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will try it! 
I dont think its a linux problemm as well, but maybe someone of you had the same troubles as I, while installing.